# Sitecore goal reports

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

Hi guys I need to create a custom report which will show all goals triggered within a time period:

Goal Name
Number of Visitors (who converted the goal)

Number of Conversions (Count of goal conversions)

Goal Value (Sum of value for goal)

Value per Visit (Goal Value / Number Visitors)

Can somebody help me with documentation or Sql Queries how to get from Analytics database these values ?

I'm using Sitecore 7.2 140526 release .

I found here structure of analytics database :

https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/report_designer_cookbook_sc65-a4.pdf but I still not anything about goal conversions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 3.Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I didn't find any documentation related to visitors who converted the goal that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: I wouldn't close the question, but if @Daren could rephrase it so that it asks specifically about which tablss the data he requires is found in, and how they are related, then it would be much improved.

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look at the report designer cookbook, 4.2.5 Page Events.

The PageEvents table contains all PageEvents. It also includes a VisitID - this is the key from the Visits table, which in turn has a VisitorID, which is key to the Visitor table. To tell which of the page events is a goal, use the PageEvents.PageEventDefinitionID, which is key to the PageEventDefinition table, which contains a column IsGoal.

That should give you the link between visitors and goals. The rest is  writing the queries.